# I can't sudo apt upgrade

Tags: linux, boot, linux-mint, apt, fstab

I have a new installation of Linux Mint and I cant run apt upgrade without getting this response. How can I fix it?

Sorry that it's in german.

```
me@mypc:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Paketaktualisierung (Upgrade) wird berechnet... Fertig
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
4 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt.
Nach dieser Operation werden 0 B Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] j
linux-image-4.15.0-48-generic (4.15.0-48.51) wird eingerichtet ...
linux-firmware (1.173.5) wird eingerichtet ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-47-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/nvme0n1p7
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
W: initramfs-tools configuration sets RESUME=UUID=704fb465-a53a-498f-b361-651d211db9b8
W: but no matching swap device is available.
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p6
I: (UUID=ce9befb5-27c4-44bf-9f18-10e0158532d8)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-47-generic with 1.
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes linux-firmware (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes linux-firmware-Skript des Paketes post-installation gab den Fehler-Ausgangsstatus 1 zurück
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic hängt ab von linux-firmware; aber:
  Paket linux-firmware ist noch nicht konfiguriert.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes linux-image-generic (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von linux-generic:
 linux-generic hängt ab von linux-image-generic (= 4.15.0.48.50); aber:
  Paket linux-image-generic ist noch nicht konfiguriert.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes linux-generic (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
Es wurde kein Apport-Bericht verfasst, da die Fehlermeldung darauf hindeutet, dass dies lediglich ein Folgefehler eines vorherigen Problems ist.
                                                                                                                                                Es wurde kein Apport-Bericht verfasst, da die Fehlermeldung darauf hindeutet, dass dies lediglich ein Folgefehler eines vorherigen Problems ist.
                                                  Trigger für linux-image-4.15.0-48-generic (4.15.0-48.51) werden verarbeitet ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-48-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/nvme0n1p7
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
W: initramfs-tools configuration sets RESUME=UUID=704fb465-a53a-498f-b361-651d211db9b8
W: but no matching swap device is available.
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/nvme0n1p6
I: (UUID=ce9befb5-27c4-44bf-9f18-10e0158532d8)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-48-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes linux-image-4.15.0-48-generic (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes linux-image-4.15.0-48-generic-Skript des Paketes post-installation gab den Fehler-Ausgangsstatus 1 zurück
Es wurde kein Apport-Bericht verfasst, da das Limit MaxReports bereits erreicht ist.
                                                                                    Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 linux-firmware
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-4.15.0-48-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

/etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p7 during installation
UUID=fb3f1ce1-f80f-4dfa-b08c-6daa8eb18874 /               btrfs   defaults,subvol=@ 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=a03d7d84-a6eb-4c88-9d95-1cda336172d0 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=9211-81D8  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/nvme0n1p8 during installation
UUID=a045b67a-4dae-43be-861e-f3a119ebcda1 /home           btrfs   defaults,subvol=@home 0       2
#swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=ce9befb5-27c4-44bf-9f18-10e0158532d8 none            swap    sw              0       0
#/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

[image: gparted]

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Messages in German won't help you get an answer because this is an English-only site.  I'm sure we have some German-speaking members, but the purpose of the site is a knowledge base, and with all the critical info in German, this won't be useful for most readers.  Run the messages through Google Translate, verify that the translation is accurate, and replace the text in the question with the translated version.

Comment: You have run out of space on your `/boot` or `/boot/efi` partition. You may have several previous installations on it. Make sure you have only the current and previous boots and completely remove any earlier ones (I usually find `synaptic` the easiest way to way to do this).

Answer (score 2):

Here's the problem: `gzip: stdout: No space left on device`

Looks like you are out of free disk space. If you have a separate boot partition, it might be too small.  You can check your availability free space with the `df -h` command and remove some unneeded files. You can also use `du -h /` to find folders which are taking up a large amount of space.

Comment: The problem is the EFI partition - there are no "large amounts of space" to be taken up, as it is only 200MB total

Answer (score 2):

You have no more room on your EFI system partition (/dev/nvme0n1p2, mounted at /boot/efi).

This can happen, if you just reuse a Microsoft EFI partition without resizing it - it is designed to hold only the Windows boot files and not to allow other OSes to store theire boot files there.

Comment: If _Pascal Deneaux_ boots their system from a LiveUSB, could they shrink the second partition, removing space from its front to make free space to expand the EFI system partition, then resize that, safely? (Always, always, backup, regardless!)

Comment: That would be my approach as well, but it might even work by just cleaning up the partition.